# Could not load file or assembly 'WebCamlib.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, windows, dll, .net-assembly, webcam

I have developed a windows application in .net which capture pictures. i have developed using Webcamlib.dll on 64 bit machine and was working fine. But when i am trying to deploy it using any CPU Mode on windows 64 bit machine.

It shows the mentioned error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WebCamlib.dll' or one of its
dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

Any idea on this?